# Re-index numeric nested arrays keys

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
$arr = [
        1 => [
              2 => "something",
              3 => "something else"
            ],
        2 => "foo br"
    ];
```

I need to restart all keys and start all of them from `0`. Based on some researches, I figured out I have to use `array_values()` function. But it just makes the keys of outer array re-index, [See](https://3v4l.org/Ia53L).

How can I apply it on the all keys of array? *(even nested ones)*

Comment: loop through the parent array and use `array_values` on each child array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) + `recursively calling` custom function:

```
function arrayValuesRecursive($array) {
    $array = array_values($array);
    $countValues = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countValues; $i++ ) {
        $subElement = $array[$i];
        if (is_array($subElement)) {
            $array[$i] = arrayValuesRecursive($subElement);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$restructuredArray = arrayValuesRecursive($array);
```

Comment: Yes this would work for the example in the question. But what about arrays contain 5 nested arrays?

Comment: @stack It should also works because it does not depends on exact nested deep, it will loop recursively through each level

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it using recursion like this:

```
function reIndex($arr) {
    $arr = array_values($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $arr[$k] = reIndex($v);
        }
    }

    return $arr; 
}

$arr = reIndex($arr);
```

Comment: Yes this would work for the example in the question. But what about arrays contain 5 nested arrays?

Comment: @stack It would also work. As far as I see this does the same as sergio's code, but it's shorter

Answer (score 1):

Hi checkout following code

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        1 => [
            2 => "something",
            3 => "something else"
        ],
        2 => "foo br"
    ];

    $reIndexedArray = array();
    foreach($arr as $arrItr){
        $reIndexedArray[] = count($arrItr) > 1 ? array_values($arrItr) : $arrItr;
    }
    print_r($reIndexedArray);
?>
```

output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => something
            [1] => something else
        )

    [1] => foo br
)
```

Comment: `count($arrItr) > 1`? And if `$arrItr` is an array with `1` item?

Comment: Yes this would work for the example in the question. But what about arrays contain 5 nested arrays?